# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'squeeze'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting the following error when trying to call(by value) a function named make_dashboard

Function call:

```
make_dashboard(x=1948, gdp_change=10, unemployment=3.75, title=title, file_name=file_name)
```

```
*Error:* AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-8f2b4601acb0> in <module>()
      1 # Fill up the parameters in the following function:
----> 2 make_dashboard(1948, 10, 3.75, title, file_name)
      3 #make_dashboard(1948, 10, unemployment=3.75, title=title, file_name=file_name)

<ipython-input-5-0d2e581d2fa5> in make_dashboard(x, gdp_change, unemployment, title, file_name)
      2     output_file(file_name)
      3     p = figure(title=title, x_axis_label='year', y_axis_label='%')
----> 4     p.line(x.squeeze(), gdp_change.squeeze(), color="firebrick", line_width=4, legend="% GDP change")
      5     p.line(x.squeeze(), unemployment.squeeze(), line_width=4, legend="% unemployed")
      6     show(p)

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'squeeze'

*Function:* def make_dashboard(x, gdp_change, unemployment, title, file_name):
    output_file(file_name)
    p = figure(title=title, x_axis_label='year', y_axis_label='%')
    p.line(x.squeeze(), gdp_change.squeeze(), color="firebrick", line_width=4, legend="% GDP change")
    p.line(x.squeeze(), unemployment.squeeze(), line_width=4, legend="% unemployed")
    show(p)
```

The attributes 'x','gdp_change' and 'unemployment' used in the function are dataframes. Kindly someone help me with this error.

Tried entering values for attributes while calling the function 
`make_dashboard(x=1948, gdp_change=10, unemployment=3.75, title=title, file_name=file_name)`

```
def make_dashboard(x, gdp_change, unemployment, title, file_name):
    output_file(file_name)
    p = figure(title=title, x_axis_label='year', y_axis_label='%')
    p.line(x.squeeze(), gdp_change.squeeze(), color="firebrick", line_width=4, legend="% GDP change")
    p.line(x.squeeze(), unemployment.squeeze(), line_width=4, legend="% unemployed")
    show(p)


make_dashboard(x=1948, gdp_change=10, unemployment=3.75, title=title, file_name=file_name)
```

expected is the dashboard displayed  based on attributes

```
Actual: Error : 
 AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-8f2b4601acb0> in <module>()
      1 # Fill up the parameters in the following function:
----> 2 make_dashboard(1948, 10, 3.75, title, file_name)
      3 #make_dashboard(1948, 10, unemployment=3.75, title=title, file_name=file_name)

<ipython-input-5-0d2e581d2fa5> in make_dashboard(x, gdp_change, unemployment, title, file_name)
      2     output_file(file_name)
      3     p = figure(title=title, x_axis_label='year', y_axis_label='%')
----> 4     p.line(x.squeeze(), gdp_change.squeeze(), color="firebrick", line_width=4, legend="% GDP change")
      5     p.line(x.squeeze(), unemployment.squeeze(), line_width=4, legend="% unemployed")
      6     show(p)

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'squeeze'
```

Comment: Are you using numpy? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html

Comment: No, using the following dependencies: import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import numpy as well in your first block of code. It's because squeeze() function is used when we want to remove 1-D entries from an array.

```
import numpy as np
```

Now, you have to make a slight changes where you are calling your "make_dashboard" function. Don't pass the attributes as int, float or list. You have to pass it as an array.

```
make_dashboard(x=np.array(x),gap_change=np.array(gap_change),unemployment=np.array(unemployment), title=title, file_name=file_name)
```

This should run the program.

Comment: thanks. was able to work with np ..

Answer (score 0):

Manipulate the code below:

```
def make_dashboard(x, gdp_change, unemployment, title, file_name):
    output_file(file_name)
    p = figure(title=title, x_axis_label='year', y_axis_label='%')
    p.line(x.squeeze(), gdp_change.squeeze(), color="firebrick", line_width=4, legend="% GDP change")
    p.line(x.squeeze(), unemployment.squeeze(), line_width=4, legend="% unemployed")
    show(p)
```